# list item options don't display correctly

Tags: html, css

I wonder if you could help me with this.

I want to display list-items but 2 problems occur.

1. The list items should be replace with a V image instead of the normal  bullet
2. The list items are displayed in 3 columns but yet the first item in the first column is shifted down slightly.

My html code

```
<div id="box2" class="features">
  <ul>
    <li>Smoking Policy</li>
    <li>Business Center</li>
    <li>Doctor</li>
    <li>Free Wifi</li>
    <li>Pets Allowed</li>
  </ul>
</div>

.features{
position:relative;
float:left;
width: 90%;
height: auto;
margin: 1% 0 0 2%;
border-radius:5px;
padding: 0% 1% 0% 1%;
font-size: 12px;
border: solid 1px #D41717;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
   -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;}

.features ul img{width: inherit;}
.features ul li{list-style-image: url('images/v-list.png');}
.features li {
display: block;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

See picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZOGm.png)

Help would be appreciated

Thx 
Jon

Comment: this may helps you to use img instead of default bullet : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-image

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that show what you tried so far? Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: maybe we don't downvote a newcomer for not properly formatting their questions instead point them to how to do it. Stuff like this makes stackoverflow harsh for a newbee.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is coming from the `display: block` of your style. and the `list-style-image` should on `ul` not `ul > li` here is a jsbin: [list-style-image](https://jsbin.com/jitovehuze/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thx mate. The list-style-image position answer was a good one. However the display:block didn't help... Appreciate your remarks.

Comment: remove `display: block` from your style and it should work. a working example is on the jsbin link in the answer above. if you find my answer helpful please vote it up and mark as accepted